# Ajax request to rails controller is setting the id parameter = "destroy"?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

so I have a weird problem where for some reason the id parameter in my delete request is being set to "destroy". Here is the code for my ajax request

```
function deleteItems(id_data, table){
  $.ajax({
    url: '/items/destroy',
    method: 'DELETE',
    processData: true,
    data: {ids: id_data },
    success: function(){
     dropItems(id_data, table)
    }
  });
 }
```

And here are the parameters I am getting in the rails controller

```
{"ids"=>["6", "19"], "controller"=>"items", "action"=>"destroy", "id"=>"destroy"}
```

If I try and set the data key to id (instead of id's) I get this

```
{"id"=>"destroy", "controller"=>"items", "action"=>"destroy"}
```

Any help in figuring out why id is being set to "destroy" would be awesome. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you're using resource routing. In that case your url should look like

```
url: '/items/:id'
```

That url  will destroy only one item.  For example:

```
url: '/items/9
```

Or you need to define new route for

```
items/destroy
```

and pass ids  as a parameters.

Comment: Thanks, your absolutely right. I just realised my mistake soon after I wrote the question, but thanks for confirming it for me.

Comment: Welcome, glad to help. Could you please accept my answer? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Really appreciate. Thanks.